# How to configure an <include> layout in xml

Tags: android, include, android-databinding

I have included a layout with an EditText into my host-layout. The imeOptions of the EditText in the include-layout should be configurable from my host-layout. Therefore I added a variable and the hook in the include-layout.

My problem is that in the host-layout I want to set the actual flag as value like this

```
app:customImeOptions="@{actionNext}"
```

By doing so I get the error "Cannot find identifier 'actionNext'". The only thing that works is setting the integer value.

```
app:customImeOptions="@{0x00000006}"
```

**The Include-Layout**

```
<data>
    ...
    
    <variable
        name="customImeOptions"
        type="Int"/>

</data>

<ConstraintLayout
    ...
    ...>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="@{customImeOptions}/>

</ConstraintLayout>
```

The Host Layout
<ConstraintLayout
...
...>

```
    <include
        layout="@layout/include_layout"
        app:customImeOptions="@{0x00000006}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the flag in the host layout one must import the corresponding class in the host-layout. In this case add this import in the data section of the host-layout

```
<data>

    <import type="android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo" />

</data>
```

Now that the host-layout knows this class it is possible to set the flag instead of the int-value like this

```
<include
        layout="@layout/include_layout"
        app:customImeOptions="@{EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT}" />
```